# Extracting related different element tags in an XML based on some equality condition on attributes values using XPATH and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, break

I need to pull data out of XML in some specific way using XPATH and XSLT

```
<data>      
    <person id="p1">         
        <name>User1</name>      
    </person>   
    <person id="p2">         
        <name>User2</name>      
    </person>  
    <person id="p3">         
        <name>User3</name>      
    </person>       
    <employee eid="emp1" pid="p1">         
        <dept>dept1</dept>      
    </employee> 
    <employee eid="emp2" pid="p3">         
        <dept>dept3</dept>      
    </employee>
    <employee eid="emp3" pid="p2">         
        <dept>dept1</dept>      
    </employee>
</data>
```

From the above example I need to create XMLs of each with the Person and the corresponding Employee elements in the output xml.  The link between these two xmls is

person.id = employee.pid

like 
XML1:

```
<person id="p1">         
<name>User1</name>      
</person>  
<employee eid="emp1" pid="p1">         
<dept>dept1</dept>      
</employee>
```

XML2:

```
<person id="p2">         
<name>User2</name>      
</person> 
<employee eid="emp3" pid="p2">         
 <dept>dept1</dept>      
</employee>
```

XML3:

```
<person id="p3">         
<name>User3</name>      
</person> 
<employee eid="emp2" pid="p3">         
<dept>dept3</dept>      
</employee>
```

I have tried many ways but not able to get this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPath is a *query* language for XML documents -- as such the evaluation of an XPath expression cannot modify an existing document or create a new XML document**.

**What you want can best be achieved using XSLT 2.0 (XSLT 1.0 if only one result document is needed):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kEmpByPid" match="employee" use="@pid"/>

 <xsl:template match="person">
  <xsl:result-document href="file:///c:/temp/delete/XML{position()}">
      <t>
             <xsl:copy-of select=".|key('kEmpByPid', @id)"/>
         </t>
     </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<data>
    <person id="p1">
        <name>User1</name>
    </person>
    <person id="p2">
        <name>User2</name>
    </person>
    <person id="p3">
        <name>User3</name>
    </person>
    <employee eid="emp1" pid="p1">
        <dept>dept1</dept>
    </employee>
    <employee eid="emp2" pid="p3">
        <dept>dept3</dept>
    </employee>
    <employee eid="emp3" pid="p2">
        <dept>dept1</dept>
    </employee>
</data>
```

the following three XML documents are created in "c:\temp\delete":

**XML1**:

```
<t>
   <person id="p1">
      <name>User1</name>
   </person>
   <employee eid="emp1" pid="p1">
      <dept>dept1</dept>
   </employee>
</t>
```

**XML2**:

```
<t>
   <person id="p2">
      <name>User2</name>
   </person>
   <employee eid="emp3" pid="p2">
      <dept>dept1</dept>
   </employee>
</t>
```

**XML3**:

```
<t>
   <person id="p3">
      <name>User3</name>
   </person>
   <employee eid="emp2" pid="p3">
      <dept>dept3</dept>
   </employee>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the below solution for my problem above.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="//person">
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@id" />
        <xsl:result-document href="file:///c:/temp/delete/XML{position()}">
        <t>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | //employee[@pid=$ID]" />
        </t>                
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just wanted to share with you.

Thanks.